# Как работать с массивом, который заполняется в другом методе?

Tags: java, массивы, javafx, поиск, scene-builder

Как работать с массивом, который заполняется в другом методе?

Comment: Работайте с ним... **как с массивом**... У него новых свойств и методов при передаче не появляется... В чем вопрос?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Обратись напрямую к массиву(полю класса)

Comment: Понял, спасибо!